# Adding images to pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, image, transparent, picturebox

I'm writing a simple game - snake. I would like to have background and my snake on it. I think that the best way is use two pictureBox (one with background and second - transparent with snake on it).

This is a good way? And how can I put several small images (snake's segments) on one picture box in different places (just copy pixel's (one after one) from image to pictureBox or maybe there is fastest way - putting all image in correct place)? I have pictureBox with background (parent) and and another, transparent (child) on it now.

The result should be look something like that:

[image: sample Image]

I've made something like that (thanks to @dotTutorials), but my snake's segments are a little bit bigger than original images and cookie is smaller. Where can be a problem?

Drawing Code:

```
public Bitmap PrinPlayground()
{

    char[,] tempPitch = play.getPitch();

    Graphics g = pb2.CreateGraphics();
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(512, 512);
    Graphics BBG = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

    Bitmap head = CookieSnake.Properties.Resources.head;
    Bitmap body01 = CookieSnake.Properties.Resources.body01;
    Bitmap tail = CookieSnake.Properties.Resources.tail;
    Bitmap cookie = CookieSnake.Properties.Resources.cookie;

    BBG.Clear(Color.Transparent);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            if (tempPitch[i, j] == 'H')
            {
                BBG.DrawImage(head, new Point(32*j, 32*i));
            }
            else if (tempPitch[i, j] == 'B')
            {
                BBG.DrawImage(body01, new Point(32*j, 32*i));
            }
            else if (tempPitch[i, j] == 'T')
            {
                BBG.DrawImage(tail, new Point(32 * j, 32 * i));
            }
            else if (tempPitch[i, j] == 'C')
            {
                BBG.DrawImage(cookie, new Point(32 * j, 32 * i));
            }
        }
    g.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0,0));
    return bitmap;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for this off-topic comment but your snake looks awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is definitely to use the 'Graphics' class. Please look further into the GDI, and the namespace [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx).

If you want to use a Picturebox representing the game space, you can easily implement graphics to a picturebox as well, by calling the member `CreateGraphics`.

I hope this helps you! :)
**Please notice that when you get into serious game development, you'll have to find a better alternative than GDI. I personally prefer the XNA library**

Example usage of GDI [This written fast, and should not be copy - pasted. However; It is a good point of origin :)]

```
    Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    Bitmap BB = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    Graphics BBG = Graphics.FromImage(BB);

    Bitmap Background = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("BackgroundPicture.png");
    Bitmap Head = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("SnakeHead.png");
    Bitmap Tail = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("SnakeTail.png");

    Point snakeLocation = new Point((BB.Width / 2) - (Head.Width / 2), (BB.Height / 2) - (Head.Height / 2));


    while (true) {
        #region Update
        // update method here!
        snakeLocation.X += 1;
        #endregion

        #region Draw
        BBG.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        BBG.DrawImage(Background, new Point(0, 0));

        BBG.DrawImage(Head, snakeLocation);
        BBG.DrawImage(Tail, new Point(snakeLocation.X - Head.Width, snakeLocation.Y));

        g.DrawImage(BB, new Point(0, 0)); // draw to screen
        #endregion
    }
```

**UPDATE:** The DrawImage method also accepts a RectangleF input. A RectangleF consits of 4 datatypes, float X, float Y, float Width and float Height.

With a RectangleF you can easily specify the size of the drawn image. Take a look at the code below:

```
public Bitmap PrinPlayground() {

            char[,] tempPitch = play.getPitch();

            Graphics g = pb2.CreateGraphics();
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            Graphics BBG = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

            Bitmap head = CookieSnake.Properties.Resources.head;
            Bitmap body01 = CookieSnake.Properties.Resources.body01;
            Bitmap tail = CookieSnake.Properties.Resources.tail;
            Bitmap cookie = CookieSnake.Properties.Resources.cookie;

            BBG.Clear(Color.Transparent);

            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
                    if (tempPitch[i, j] == 'H') {
                        BBG.DrawImage(head, new RectangleF(new Point(32 * j, 32 * i), new SizeF(/*Adjust the size after your pleasure*/32, 32)));
                    }
                    else if (tempPitch[i, j] == 'B') {
                        BBG.DrawImage(body01, new RectangleF(new Point(32 * j, 32 * i), new SizeF(32, 32)));
                    }
                    else if (tempPitch[i, j] == 'T') {
                        BBG.DrawImage(tail, new RectangleF(new Point(32 * j, 32 * i), new SizeF(32, 32)));
                    }
                    else if (tempPitch[i, j] == 'C') {
                        BBG.DrawImage(cookie, new RectangleF(new Point(32 * j, 32 * i), new SizeF(/*Half the size of the head [Adjust after your needs!]*/32 / 2, 32 / 2)));
                    }
                }
            g.DrawImage(bitmap, new Point(0, 0));
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know this - I wanted to know that idea with two picturebox is correct and I want to ask that there is simpler way to put small images (snake's segments) on pictureBox that coping every pixels (just putting it to correct pleace).

And game is only way to show something completly different (main topic of project - using different controllers like KINECT etc) - I just think that it is better way than text and digits in console.

Comment: Hmmm. I am not sure if I understand you completely. But, you may be looking for the Bitmap.LockBits function.

Comment: It works, but I have a little problem - a picture which is on screen is a little bit bigger than original image. Do you know where can be the problem? (I think about snake's segments). Look at my editted Question, please :)